# How to use multiple 'where' clause with multiple tables with Eloquent ORM?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database query with multiple 'JOIN' statements in my Laravel application, but I don't know how to correctly add a where clause to it.

Here is my function:

```
    return Topic::join('blogs', 'topics.blog_id', '=', 'blogs.id')
            ->join('blog_subscriptions as us', function ($j) use ($userId){
                  $j->on('us.blog_id', '=', 'blogs.id')
                    ->where('us.user_id', '=', $userId);
            })
            ->take(Config::get('topic.topics_per_page'))
            ->offset($offset)
            ->get(['topics.*']);
```

I would like to add a 'where' clause to the  'topics' table - so I add a line where('rating', '>', 1), after "Topic::", so the code is like this:

```
Topic::where('rating', '>', 1)
            ->join('blogs', 'topics.blog_id', '=', 'blogs.id')
            ->join('blog_subscriptions as us', function ($j) use ($userId){
                $j->on('us.blog_id', '=', 'blogs.id')
                ->where('us.user_id', '=', $userId);
            })
            ->take(Config::get('topic.topics_per_page'))
            ->offset($offset)
            ->get(['topics.*']);
```

but it only leads to an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'rating' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `topics`.* from `topics` inner join `blogs` on `topics`.`blog_id` = `blogs`.`id` inner join `blog_subscriptions` as `us` on `us`.`blog_id` = `blogs`.`id` and `us`.`user_id` = 1 where `rating` > 1 limit 2 offset 0)

Comment: Try `topics.rating` instead of `rating`

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thank you. It seems to me, that I should deepen my SQL knowledge, rather then Eloquent?

Comment: Well I can't hurt to do both. In this case it was mostly correct reading of the error message. I'm going to write a full answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, the column `rating` is ambiguous. Meaning SQL can't tell which column you mean because there might be another one in your join that's named `rating` as well.

In this situation it helps to clarify in which table the field is. This is simply done by using the `[table].[field]` syntax

```
where('topics.rating', '>', 1)
```